# Merge two XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have two xml, I have to merge a specific node

This is the first one:

```
<ContactEmployees>
  <row>
    <Name>NAME</Name>
    <Position>Mag</Position>
    <Phone1>number</Phone1>
    <E_Mail>mail</E_Mail>
    <InternalCode>11</InternalCode>
    <Gender>gt_Undefined</Gender>
    <Active>tYES</Active>
    <FirstName>Tizio</FirstName>
    <BlockSendingMarketingContent>tNO</BlockSendingMarketingContent>
  </row>
</ContactEmployees>
```

This is the second:

```
<ContactEmployees>
      <row>
        <CardCode>1000010</CardCode>
        <Name>NAME</Name>
        <Position>Mag</Position>
        <Phone1>number</Phone1>
        <E_Mail>mail</E_Mail>
        <InternalCode>11</InternalCode>
        <Gender>gt_Undefined</Gender>
        <Active>tYES</Active>
        <BlockSendingMarketingContent>tNO</BlockSendingMarketingContent>
      </row>
      <row>
        <CardCode>1000010</CardCode>
        <Name>Prova</Name>
        <InternalCode>2703</InternalCode>
        <PlaceOfBirth>-1</PlaceOfBirth>
        <Gender>gt_Undefined</Gender>
        <Active>tYES</Active>
        <FirstName>Prova</FirstName>
        <BlockSendingMarketingContent>tNO</BlockSendingMarketingContent>
      </row>
    </ContactEmployees>
```

This is the result that I expect after the merge:

```
<ContactEmployees>
       <row>
        <Name>NAME</Name>
        <Position>Mag</Position>
        <Phone1>number</Phone1>
        <E_Mail>mail</E_Mail>
        <InternalCode>11</InternalCode>
        <Gender>gt_Undefined</Gender>
        <Active>tYES</Active>
        <FirstName>Tizio</FirstName>
        <BlockSendingMarketingContent>tNO</BlockSendingMarketingContent>
      </row>
      <row>
        <CardCode>1000010</CardCode>
        <Name>Prova</Name>
        <InternalCode>2703</InternalCode>
        <PlaceOfBirth>-1</PlaceOfBirth>
        <Gender>gt_Undefined</Gender>
        <Active>tYES</Active>
        <FirstName>Prova</FirstName>
        <BlockSendingMarketingContent>tNO</BlockSendingMarketingContent>
      </row>
    </ContactEmployees>
```

I try to do `IEnumerable<XElement> merge = xdoc.Root.Descendants("ContactEmployees").Concat("ContactEmployees"));`
xdoc is all my xml document of which the "ContactEmployees" node is part, but the concat method generates an xml with three nodes or queues all the nodes, I tried union but excludes the second xml and I do not understand how I can do maybe with a query trying to see through the InternalCode attribute because I can not modify it in any way so it is unique?

-Edit-
I reviewed the situation, Internalcode can be different (they are data of a database) and the Name can modify it (Name, InternalCode and CardCode are the key of my table), so I actually have to merge the changes on the same row and add from the second xml the new lines, I do not know how feasible it can be

Comment: So the merge rule is: add all those <row> elements from the second document to the first document for which there is not yet a <row> element with same <name>?

Comment: yes this is the rule

Comment: Are the names unique?  It looks like the second is missing the Code but has additional field FirstName.

Comment: the names no but InternalCode yes

Comment: I reviewed the situation, Internalcode can be different (they are data of a database) and the Name can modify it (Name, InternalCode and CardCode are the key of my table), so I actually have to merge the changes on the same row and add from the second xml the new lines, I do not know how feasible it can be

Comment: Could you please add this new requirement to your question? See [edit]

Comment: I edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with an explicit foreach loop:

```cs
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<ContactEmployees>
  <row>
    <Name>NAME</Name>
    <Position>Mag</Position>
    <Phone1>number</Phone1>
    <E_Mail>mail</E_Mail>
    <InternalCode>11</InternalCode>
    <Gender>gt_Undefined</Gender>
    <Active>tYES</Active>
    <FirstName>Tizio</FirstName>
    <BlockSendingMarketingContent>tNO</BlockSendingMarketingContent>
  </row>
</ContactEmployees>");

var doc2 = XDocument.Parse(@"<ContactEmployees>
      <row>
        <CardCode>1000010</CardCode>
        <Name>NAME</Name>
        <Position>Mag</Position>
        <Phone1>number</Phone1>
        <E_Mail>mail</E_Mail>
        <InternalCode>11</InternalCode>
        <Gender>gt_Undefined</Gender>
        <Active>tYES</Active>
        <BlockSendingMarketingContent>tNO</BlockSendingMarketingContent>
      </row>
      <row>
        <CardCode>1000010</CardCode>
        <Name>Prova</Name>
        <InternalCode>2703</InternalCode>
        <PlaceOfBirth>-1</PlaceOfBirth>
        <Gender>gt_Undefined</Gender>
        <Active>tYES</Active>
        <FirstName>Prova</FirstName>
        <BlockSendingMarketingContent>tNO</BlockSendingMarketingContent>
      </row>
    </ContactEmployees>");
    
var employees = doc.Root;

var employees2 = doc2.Root;

foreach (var row2 in employees2.Elements("row"))
{
    // the following may be adapted to whatever criterion shall be used
    // to identify a record
    var id2 = row2.Element("InternalCode").Value;
    var row = employees.Elements("row").FirstOrDefault(r => r.Element("InternalCode").Value == id2);

    if (row == null)
    {
        // row not found in doc, so add it
        employees.Add(row2);
    }
    else
    {
        // row found; maybe update it, e.g.
        var nameElement2 = row2.Element("Name");
        if (nameElement2 != null)
        {
            var nameElement = row.Element("Name");
            if (nameElement == null)
                nameElement = nameElement2;
            else
                nameElement.Value = nameElement2.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting XML is in `doc`.

Comment: I reviewed the situation, Internalcode can be different (they are data of a database) and the Name can modify it (Name, InternalCode and CardCode are the key of my table), so I actually have to merge the changes on the same row and add from the second xml the new lines, I do not know how feasible it can be

Comment: @r.pezzolati Updated my answer so the code locations where such adaptations have to be implemented are clear.

Comment: I try but https://pastebin.com/k387NkP3 I know it's a mess, but I do not know how to fix it all

Comment: The sample data you linked is different from that given in your question. Also, I have no idea where e.e. "NAME2" in the desired result comes from. Recommendation: 1. formulate clearly the criteria for considering a row as "the same entry", 2. define clearly what shall be updated in case a row is already there.

Comment: You're right, the Name is changed from my management application, retrieve the xml of the costumer and with a service replico the changes on another database, only on the second db I have maybe more row of the tag ContactEmployees and to avoid overwriting I have to add 'xml starting the extra rows and updating those changed, only that the InternalCode may not be the same